# Extracting a few bits of data from .txt file

Tags: r, text, automation

After a long morning, I have given up!

I have the following text file: StationLog.txt

Containing the following:

```
Version      = 2.0
StationName  = STN67_P70
BeginTime    = 2017-10-06.03:25:00
EndTime      = 2017-10-06.03:55:00
IgnoreNo     = 5000
PumpedVolume = 0
```

I need to extract the BeginTime, EndTime and StationName, those headings are fine, as values which feeds into another bit of code.

The idea is I don't have to do it manually as there will be lots of these files in time.

Following various other guides I have to this far:

```
a <- read.fwf("StationLog.txt", c(37,100), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
a <- a[grep("=", a$V1), ]
a <- cbind(
  do.call( rbind, strsplit(a$V1, "=\\s+") )
```

But hit a bit of a wall, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `read.table` function, you can use the arguments to do what you want.

The following proposal will work if you have only one `=` per row, and if the BeginTime, EndTime and StationName have the same writing in all files:

```
read.table(
  file            ="StationLog.txt",
  header          =FALSE, # No column names
  sep             ="=",   # separator character
  strip.white     =TRUE,  # remove multiple white character
  row.names       =1,     # the first column contains the rownames
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)[c("BeginTime", "EndTime", "StationName"), # extract the 3 infos based on their names corresponding to the rownames
  ,drop=FALSE] # keep the data.frame format
```

And the result:

```
                             V2
BeginTime   2017-10-06.03:25:00
EndTime     2017-10-06.03:55:00
StationName           STN67_P70
```

Comment: Great, that's worked a treat, I can then extract the bits needed from the df. Cheers your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the whole thing as a multiline string:

data:

```
txt_string <- "Version      = 2.0
StationName  = STN67_P70
BeginTime    = 2017-10-06.03:25:00
EndTime      = 2017-10-06.03:55:00
IgnoreNo     = 5000
PumpedVolume = 0"

stationName<- regmatches(txt_string, gregexpr("StationName\\s+=\\s+\\K\\S+" ,txt_string, perl = T))
beginTime  <- regmatches(txt_string, gregexpr("BeginTime\\s+=\\s+\\K\\S+" ,txt_string, perl = T))
endTime    <- regmatches(txt_string, gregexpr("EndTime\\s+=\\s+\\K\\S+" ,txt_string, perl = T))

do.call(cbind, c(stationName, beginTime, endTime))

#     [,1]        [,2]                  [,3]                 
#[1,] "STN67_P70" "2017-10-06.03:25:00" "2017-10-06.03:55:00"
```

Comment: Cheers for replying Andre
That's the path I started down, but I can't get my head around the \\s+= bit, what it means, I am sure its a method of selecting whats in there, but it puzzled me, if you wouldn't mind explaining for future reference?

Comment: Hey, it's called regular expression. You can reference what the "bits" are doing on www.regex101.com for e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method:

```
# use the filename vs this embedded example
station_info <-   readLines(textConnection("Version      = 2.0
StationName  = STN67_P70
BeginTime    = 2017-10-06.03:25:00
EndTime      = 2017-10-06.03:55:00
IgnoreNo     = 5000
PumpedVolume = 0"))
```

base:

```
as.list(sapply(
  strsplit(station_info, split = "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"),
  function(x) setNames(x[2], x[1])
)) -> station_info

str(station_info, 1)
## List of 6
##  $ Version     : chr "2.0"
##  $ StationName : chr "STN67_P70"
##  $ BeginTime   : chr "2017-10-06.03:25:00"
##  $ EndTime     : chr "2017-10-06.03:55:00"
##  $ IgnoreNo    : chr "5000"
##  $ PumpedVolume: chr "0"
```

tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

# use the filename vs this embedded example
station_info <-   readLines(textConnection("Version      = 2.0
StationName  = STN67_P70
BeginTime    = 2017-10-06.03:25:00
EndTime      = 2017-10-06.03:55:00
IgnoreNo     = 5000
PumpedVolume = 0"))

str_split(station_info, pattern = "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*") %>% 
  map(~set_names(.x[2], .x[1])) %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  str(1)
```

Wrapping the base version (to avoid dependencies) into a function so you can re-use it for other stations:

```
read_station_metadata <- function(path) {

  path <- path.expand(path)
  stopifnot(file.exists(path))

  station_info <- readLines(path, warn = FALSE)

  as.list(sapply(
    strsplit(station_info, split = "[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"),
    function(x) setNames(x[2], x[1])
  ))

}
```

Comment: Cheers for your detailed reply, my aim was to put it into a function eventually so that's ideal! Thanks, although I have just opened up a new can of worms. Many thanks